# Android Data Binding: context or ContextCompat?

Tags: android, android-context, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

If I am using android data binding with `ViewModel`s to, for instance, set the color of a view, I have a few options:

```
<View ... 
    background="@color/foo" />
```

or

```
class MyViewModel(context: Application): AndroidViewModel(context) {
    // this is a dramatic oversimplification, but for illustration purposes...
    fun theColor: Int = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.foo)
}
```

```
<View ... 
    background="@{viewModel.theColor}" />
```

or

```
class MyViewModel(context: Application): AndroidViewModel(context) {
    fun theColor: Int = R.color.foo
}
```

```
<View ... 
    background="@{context.getColor(viewModel.theColor)}" />
```

Assuming that theming is important to me, does it make a difference?  Specifically, I mean the difference between the color returned by `ContextCompat` and the one returned by whatever `Context` is used by the data binding expression.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is the `context` variable of your viewmodel coming from?

Comment: Should've clarified:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel

Comment: No need to clarify, it is only that, as far as I know, you need to use `getApplication()` in order to get a context because `context` isn't a property of the viewmodel.

Comment: Also valid.  And in fact that's closer to what I'm doing in practice (my application context is dependency-injected).

Comment: `ContextCompat` is not a `Context` object. `ContextCompat` is just a helper for `Context`

Comment: Am aware.  Just want to know if there's a difference in the `Color` that is returned (i.e. is it correctly-themed or not and for what API levels).

Comment: IMHO there is no difference. `ContextCompat` only helps you support Android versions lower than 23

Comment: Isn't the colour just an integer with alpha, red, green and blue? Hard to see why (and how) it could be different depending on the way in which it gets retrieved.

Comment: Read the doc on the method.  The context determines the theme from which the color is retrieved given a specific resource ID from R.color.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int)